# Unable to share whatsapp videos on web whatsapp

Tags: ffmpeg, video, whatsapp

Recently web.whatsapp.com will not share new videos created by ffmpeg, using the same code to generate them.

[image]

However videos from the same code still work on whatsapp.

Does anybody know the correct ffmpeg settings to get the mp4s to work?

The video files were taken on a gopro 10 with the follow command:

`ffmpeg  -i some.mp4 -s 1980x1080 -c:a copy sd.mp4`

Broken file: 2mb https://drive.google.com/file/d/124Ha4wbKnmrIrHDQYXpWB_bZMECu03b6/view?usp=sharing

Working File: 31.5mb
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SSfIa3xM0DDvO_o1hdeSO_Yj9OoEYvwX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please add the FFmpeg command line you are using for creating the MP4 video files? Isn't is browser dependent? Is there an issue sharing the video or playing the video?

Comment: I have updated the question, thank you. I have shared the 2 video files themsevles too. Both using ffmpeg to convert.

Comment: The video `broken.mp4` is working in my PC. The video `working.mp4` is not working, I am getting a message that the file is too large (the size limit is 16MB).

Comment: And what is scary is... I reset my machine and it worked... I used the same code to create a new video it does not work... Some hours later... it works, fascinating. Oddly my size limit is 64mb. I wonder if it is limited in different countries?

Comment: I had the same problem and realized that the audiocodec was the culprit. I know for sure that WhatsApp can't handle DTS. Maybe there's a few more that won't work, so try to change it.